# how to handle SMTPSendFailedException in Java Programmatically

Tags: java, email, smtp

I involved in SMTP Error Handling issues. Whenever SMTPSendFailedException happens i need to re-establish the connection. Could you please suggest me how to handle this in programmatically?

Error Code from Logs:

```
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 451 Internal error
```

Thanks,
enthiran

Answer (score 0):

Try surrounding the call to the method in a try-catch block, like this:

```
private int numOfTries = 0;
public void doStuff() {
    try {
        connectAndCall();
    } catch(SMTPSendFailedException e) {
        System.err.println("Something went wrong, try again. The error was: " + e.getMessage());
        numOfTries ++;
        if(numOfTries <= 5) {
            doStuff();
        }
    }
}
```

I used the `numOfTries` variable to make sure it didn't keep calling forever and lock your application, but you can increase or decrease the amount of tries permitted.

Comment: I want to reestablish the connection when such exception happens. I would like to know what are the different type of return code belongs to this exception

Comment: @SurenthiranT To get the error code, inside of the `catch` block, you can use `e.getReturnCode()` to get an `Integer` that is the return code.

Comment: when the application execute the line  

transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());

And Our SMTP connection remain active on 24/7 and due to that sometime sending email failed with error Code : 421 (Too Many Messages in a Session) .

we would like to put a fix something like "RESET the SMTP connection" when the exception happens "SMTPSendFailedException: 421 Error: too many messages in one session"

Do you have any idea how to achieve this. Please help me on this

Comment: Hm, I've never worked specifically with JavaMail, so I'm not an expert. Have you looked through the docs?